# ¿Cómo ordenar los datos de un ComboBox?

Tags: c#, combobox

Tengo 2 RadioButton y al momento de seleccionar uno por ejemplo el radiobutton llamado Ascendente quiero que los numeros que estan en el ComboBox se ordenen ASCENDENTEMENTE... Quisiera saber cómo poder hacer eso.

El codigo sigiente agrega datos al numeros al ComboBox:

```
private int Recursividad(int inicio, int fin, int incremento)
{
    if (inicio > fin)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        this.cmbValor.Items.Add(inicio);
        return Recursividad(inicio + incremento, fin, incremento);
    }
}

private void BtnEjecutar_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int inicio = 0;
    int fin = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCantidad.Text);
    int incremento = Convert.ToInt32(this.txtIncremento.Text);
    Recursividad(inicio, fin, incremento);
}
```

Comment: Depende de cómo agregás los números al `ComboBox`, porque la propiedad `Sorted`, por ejemplo, ordena pero el `ComboBox` no debe estar enlazado a datos, y sólo lo hacen en forma **ascendente**. Si pudieras dar más información, con que muestres el código que estás usando para colocar los números en el `ComboBox` sería suficiente. Recuerda que si necesitas ayuda para saber cómo publicar puedes consultar [help]

Comment: Siii ya agregue el codigo de como lo agrego

Comment: si estas llenando un combo con numeros para que una funcion recursiva? no seria mas simple con un simple for

Comment: @LeandroTuttini apuesto que es un ejercicio de algún tipo de curso de programación y por ello se *impone* el uso de recursividad.

Answer (score 1):

Viendo el código me surge la misma pregunta que te hizo @Leandro Tuttini

Yo también haría esa tarea con un bucle `for`, y para agregar los números al `comboBox`, usaría una lista genérica de enteros, pero también se puede usar un `dataView`:

```c#
List<int> lista = new List<int>();
```

Es decir que los números se agregarán a la lista:

```c#
lista.Add(inicio);    // En lugar de:    this.cmbValor.Items.Add(inicio);
```

A continuación, la lista se enlazará al `ComboBox`:

```c#
this.cmbValor.DataSource = lista;
```

Para ordenar ascendentemente:

```c#
this.cmbValor.DataSource = null;
lista.Sort();
this.cmbValor.DataSource = lista;
```

Y descendentemente:

```c#
this.cmbValor.DataSource = null;
lista.Reverse();
this.cmbValor.DataSource = lista;
```

Tener en cuenta que se necesita la lista ordenada ascendentemente para que `Reverse()` ordene descendentemente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo llamando a una funcion como esta:

```
private void InsertarNumero(int nuevoNumero)
{
    int index = 0;
    foreach (Object obj in comboBox1.Items)
    {
        if (nuevoNumero >= (int)obj) index++;
    }
    cmbValor.Items.Insert(index, nuevoNumero);
}
```